# Can't get Kepware to run on win 7 64 bit service pack 1

Tags: windows-7

I have been using kepware on vista for a few years with no problems. Kepware installs ok on win7 64 home premium, but when i run it it gives error message "servermain.exe has stopped working". servermain.exe is kepware.
i have run servermain in win nt win xp and win vista compatibility mode as administration in win 7 , still same error message.
Kepware is a server that communicates with PLCs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[According to their site](http://www.kepware.com/Support_Center/doc_system_requirements.asp), the latest versions work with newer versions of Windows including Windows 7, 8 and server 2012.

> Operating Systems:
>
> - Windows Server 2012*
> - Windows 8*
> - Windows Server 2008 R2*
> - Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate*
> - Windows Server 2008*
> - Windows Vista Business, Enterprise and Ultimate*
> - Windows Server 2003 (Service Pack 2)*
> - Windows XP Professional (Service Pack 2)*
> - Windows 2000 (Update Rollup 1 for Service Pack 4)**

So if you haven't upgraded in a few years, it's probably time to [contact Kepware](http://www.kepware.com/contact/) about an upgrade.

Comment: The cost to upgrade is too high for this project.